# Unity native network plugin written in C

Tags: unity-game-engine, plugins

For some reasons, I must implement my own network for my Unity Client in C. So I just looked around Unity native plugins, which allow me to code my network in C and be used by my client.
My server is written in C and should communicate with my Unity Client.

My protocol is already built, I would like to implement all the network into the plugin i.e connection to server, then receiving, and deserializing data into C structures.

Im wondering about the plugin limitations. I was about to create a `HandlerCallbackRegister` class that allows from the C# (from Unity) to register the different callbacks for each network message, but how are compatible the function prototypes between C# en C?

I mean, a callback could be e.g `onPlayerConnect(size_t clientId, struct player_connect_message *msg);` but how is this possible to define such a function like this callback in C# ? Will the C# struct be converted to a C struct ? What about size_t ? I'm kinda confused, if someone could link me an example or some explanations.

Thanks in advance

Comment: type conversion on crossing managed border is called marshalling, google that and you'll find some more information. One thing to keep in mind is that unity doesn't love callbacks that happen outside its main thread, so you'll need some sort of queueing mechanism (i.e. add stuff to a list and read on Update())

Comment: Oh interresting.. Thanks it was useful

Comment: @zambari what about this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.IssuePluginEvent.html it seems to be an unity "standard" queue for what im looking for, no?

Comment: The C# part would define the callbacks with my C API, that will hold it. Then, if I could call GL.IssuePluginEvent from the C plugin, it should work